# How to update a column of type array with postgresql and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a column for a table that was created with following ruby on rails migration

```
def change    
    add_column :matches, :st_history, :smallint, array: true, default: []
end
```

on a postresql database. I wish to reset all values of the column back to default. I have tried

```
Match.update_all(st_history: [])
```

but this does not change any of the fields.  Looking at the [api documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), it states that 'It should receive only values that can be passed as-is to the SQL database', so I suspect that the array is a complex datatype that will not work with a simple update_all command. The database has many millions of rows, so I do not want to update each row individually. What is a fast way of doing this?

Comment: I believe it works. Did you reload your models and check?

Comment: tell me whether the answer I provided was helpful or not

Comment: EJ2015, you were right, I just forgot to reload. Do you want to put this as an answer, I will accept it. It is too late to delete the question as someone has put an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually works. Just need to reload.

Comment: It turned out that although this works, but would take 80 hours to use on my database, so I ended up using Aniket's answer which only took a few seconds.

Comment: Just curious, how big is your db? `update_all` sends one SQL command to db, skipping ActiveRecord completely. Why would it take that long?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by creating a migration .And can give a default value

```
update_column :table_name, :col_name, :integer, array: true, null: false, default '{}'
```

Comment: Aniket, it should be 'change_column' not 'update_column'. For a large database this approach is magic. On my database it only took a few seconds instead of the 80 hours for my original approach.